# Loop through each line of text file and run command against each

Tags: powershell, for-loop, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to adjust some code which is shown below and hitting walls.

The commandline appears as:

```
cmd.exe /U /C "C:\Program Files\StorageCraft\ShadowProtect\VerifyImages.cmd <PathOfDirectoryWhichContainsImageFiles> <PathToOutputLogFile>
```

The code basically runs an image verify command against all md5 files in a directory. The problem is that some directories have >200 md5 files and I only want to verify the files created in the last 24 hrs.

I have been able to create a list of the files created in the last 24hrs and output to a text file using a powershell command.

Is it possible to adjust the script below so that it reads the text file line by line and runs the VERIFY_SUB against each? I have tried using the FOR /F command with little luck to this point.

Thanks in advance.

```
REM *** START OF MAIN ROUTINE ***
SETLOCAL
PUSHD
CD /D %~dp0

REM Strip the outer quotes off of the directory parameter
SET PARAM_DIR=%1
SET PARAM_DIR=###%PARAM_DIR%###
SET PARAM_DIR=%PARAM_DIR:"###=%
SET PARAM_DIR=%PARAM_DIR:###"=%
SET PARAM_DIR=%PARAM_DIR:###=%

REM Strip the outer quotes off of the output log file parameter
SET PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE=%2
SET PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE=###%PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE%###
SET PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE=%PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE:"###=%
SET PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE=%PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE:###"=%
SET PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE=%PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE:###=%


FOR %%A IN ("%PARAM_DIR%\*.md5") DO (call :VERIFY_SUB "%%A" "%PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE%")

POPD
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF
REM *** END OF MAIN ROUTINE ***


:VERIFY_SUB
@ECHO VERIFYING MD5 FILE %1
@ECHO VERIFYING MD5 FILE %1 >> %2
image.exe v %1 >> %2
@ECHO. >> %2
@ECHO. >> %2
@ECHO. >> %2
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: You know PowerShell has `Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5` if you want to move the verification entirely to PS, that might be worth a look. Can you show your `for /f` code that didn't work?

Comment: To strip off surrounding quotes of parameters, use `%~1`...